# Float to int error

Tags: php, casting, int

Yesterday I was helping some one and got a weird error which I could not explain to him how it worked.

The code (tested on 3 machines (PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4))

```
// (float)65.35
$percentage = round(65.351, 2);
// (float) 6535
$total = $percentage * 100;
// (int) 6534
$int = (int) $total;
```

What is suspected was that the int value would be `6535` but it ended up being `6534`.

Could some one explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how [floating point](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) (read the warning in this link!) values are stored in memory. Indeed after the first operation you don't have an exact decimal value, but a rounded value. Probably 65.34999999 or so. (The value is stored as a list of bits (0/1))

This is why when talking about money, developers don't store dollars/euros but rather the amount of cents. This way they avoid working with floats that are less precise for decimals, but rather work with integers, that are precise.

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually have 65.35 after the first operation.

```
>>> '%.20f' % (65.351 - 0.001,)
'65.34999999999999431566'
```

Either start with an integral value scaled appropriately in the first place, don't attempt to convert the value to an integer, or add a small value before taking the integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `round` instead of `int`

```
round($total)
```

Comment: True that was the solution but not really what I asked for, because I was looking for why and not how

Answer (score 0):

```
$r=$explode('.',$total);
debug($r);
```

Comment: at least try and explain what you mean